# CentOS: Alert all desktop users from command-line

Tags: command-line, console, desktop-environment, notifications

How can I notify all online (Desktop) users from the command-line?

I know that if I want that I get notified when something is done, I just do like this:

```
sudo apt-get update | notify-send "apt-get update" "update finished"
```

What should I use to notify all users (or some specific user)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [wall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall).  On my KDE machine, a small panel pops up with the message sent with wall.  Of course, the message also appears in all terminals, but maybe your users do not have a terminal open.  Example:

```
echo "It is 9 o'clock and all is well." | wall
```

Comment: wall -- send a message to everybodys terminal. I tryed it and it only send messages to terminal... on my desktop doesn't apear any message... Maybe CentOS work in a different way?

Comment: Interesting that KDE catches those, but Gnome doesn't seem to, nor do other more basic window managers. However, there is almost always a notification API of some kind, the question is how to reliable access it across all users!